# Python: "in" does not recognize values in DataFrame column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an excerpt from a DataFrame "IRAData" and a Column called 'Labels':

```
380       u'itator-Research'
381       u'itator-OnSystem'
382    u'itator-QueryClient'
383       u'itator-OnSystem'
384       u'itator-OnSystem'
385       u'itator-OnSystem'
386       u'itator-OnSystem'
387       u'itator-OnSystem'
388       u'itator-OnSystem'
Name: Labels, dtype: object
```

But when I run the following code, I get "False" output:

```
print(u'itator-QueryClient' in IRAData['Labels'])
```

Same goes for the other values in the column and when I remove the unicode 'u'. 
Anyone have an idea as to why?

EDIT: The solution that I placed in a comment below worked. Did not need to attempt the answer to the suggested duplicate question.

Comment: This ended up working for me:  

In: print filter(lambda x: u'itator-QueryClient' in x, IRAData['Labels']  

Out: ["u'itator-QueryClient'", "u'itator-QueryClient'"]

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to avoid this problems is to correctly import the data.

You store  `"u'itator-QueryClient'"` where `u` is a raw marker of unicode string,
when `'itator-QueryClient'` is the good information to store here.

For example from this html page, just select and copy the lines 381 to 384 an invoque :

```
In [498]: import ast
In [499]: pd.read_clipboard(names=['value'],index_col=0,header=None,\
converters={'value': ast.literal_eval})
Out[499]: 
                  value
381     itator-OnSystem
382  itator-QueryClient
383     itator-OnSystem
384     itator-OnSystem
```

Then `'itator-QueryClient' in IRAData['value']` will be evaluated to `True`.